# Inheritance and dunder methods?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am currently learning OOP and ran into a problem of dunder methods and inheritance.

I have 2 parent classes (both with their own init) that inherit to a subclass, and i want a string representation of the data initialized in all the classes, together.

This is the problem:

```py
#Parent class 1:

class Contact:

    all_contacts = []

    def __init__(self,name='',email='',**kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'the name is {self.name}, and the mail is {self.mail}.'

#Parent class 2:

class AddressHolder:
    def __init__(self, street='', city='', state='', code='', **kwargs):
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.code = code

    def __str__(self):
        return f'the street is {self.street}, the city is {self.city}, 
               the state is {self.state}, the code is {self.code}'

#Subclass that inherits from both parent classes:

class Friends(Contact, AddressHolder):
    def __init__(self, phone='', **kwargs):
        self.phone = phone
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'''The phone is {self.phone}.'''

#The instance of the class

f = Friends(phone='aphone', name='aname', mail='amail', 
street='astreet', city='acity', state='astate', code='acode')

print(f)
```

This will only print phone initialization.

Tried this to make it so all `__str__` are printed, but it didn't worked:

```py
    def __str__(self):
        super(Contact.self).__str__()
        super(AddressHolder.self).__str__()
        return f'''The phone is {self.phone}.'''
```

Originally, i tried to put all into the `Friends` subclass like this since it was inherited, it should work:

```py
    def __str__(self):
        return f'''The phone is {self.phone},
                    the street is {self.street},
                    the city is {self.city},
                    the state is {self.state},
                    the code is {self.code},
                    the name is {self.name},
                    and the mail is {self.mail}.'''
```

But i got a ````AttributeError: 'Friends' object has no attribute 'street'``` error (wasn't the point of inheritance that i could work on the subclass with the parent class data?).

I gave each class their own `__str__` which is arguably bad code but doesn't work either.

How can i make print all the data of the inherited classes plus the subclass?

What is the limit of inheritance if i got a "[subclass] has no attribute" error?

Comment: `super(Contact.self).__str__()` is not how you use super...

Comment: I was looking questions involving old code before ask, so decided to try anyway.

Comment: In any case, you aren't using anything with what is returned by `__str__` for each of your attempted parent-class method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your base classes cooperative, by having them both call `super().__init__()` too:

```
class Contact:

    all_contacts = []

    def __init__(self, name='', email='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)
```

and

```
class AddressHolder:
    def __init__(self, street='', city='', state='', code='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.code = code

    def __str__(self):
        return f'the street is {self.street}, the city is {self.city}, 
               the state is {self.state}, the code is {self.code}'
```

This works because `super()` searches for the named attribute (`__init__` here) in the base classes of `type(self)` Method Resolution Order (MRO), starting at the current class (the class where the method is defined). For an instance of `Friends`, the MRO is:

```
>>> Friends.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Friends'>, <class '__main__.Contact'>, <class '__main__.AddressHolder'>, <class 'object'>)
```

You already are using keyword arguments to pass on extra arguments, so you'll end up with an empty `kwargs` dictionary at the end of your MRO, effectively calling `object.__init__()` with no arguments.

Note that you can also use `super()` in the `__str__` method:

```
class Contact:
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([
            f'the name is {self.name}, and the mail is {self.mail}.',
            super().__str__()
        ])

class AddressHolder:
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([
            f'the street is {self.street}, the city is {self.city}, '
            f'the state is {self.state}, the code is {self.code}',
            super().__str__()
        ])

class Friends(Contact, AddressHolder):
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([
            f'The phone is {self.phone}.',
            super().__str__()
```

This works for any attribute that `object` defines:

```
>>> print(*dir(object()), sep="\n")
__class__
__delattr__
__dir__
__doc__
__eq__
__format__
__ge__
__getattribute__
__gt__
__hash__
__init__
__init_subclass__
__le__
__lt__
__ne__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__setattr__
__sizeof__
__str__
__subclasshook__
```

Comment: I haven't seen super() on the parent class (some books actually tell you that HAVE to inherit from some class to use a super). I guess i have to research more about it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you don't explicitly write a parent class, then your parent class is `object`; so either way, you do have a parent class to call `super().__init__` on.

Comment: @Flonne: as long as the parent class has the method, this works. `object` is the ultimate base class, and it has a `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and do something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __str__(self):
        return self.a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return self.b

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        B.__init__(self, b)
        self.c = c

    def __str__(self):
        return A.__str__(self) + B.__str__(self) + self.c

c = C("a", "b", "c")
print(c)
```

This will print out `abc`.
Just replace a, b, and c with the values that you want.