# What does it mean when a parent class has a super()?

Tags: python, oop, super

As far as i know, `super()` is used to call the methods overwritten in the subclass (like an overwritten `__init__` in the subclass).

Also, i know that all python classes inherit from a special class called `object`.

While studying OOP i ran into a weird example:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__')
        super().__init__()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('B.__init__')
        super().__init__()

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('C.__init__')
        super().__init__()
```

I understand most of this except...why does class A has a `super().__init__()`? It's the parent class, it shouldn't need to inherit from anyone. And the special `object` class doesn't do anything so i don't know why it would need it.

This is not the only case i have seen a `super` in the parent class, in a previous question i made, a solution to aproblem involved it but i didn't understood it. I also can't find an easy explanation of this usage of `super()` inheritance.

In simple terms...why would i need to use `super()` in a parent class?

Comment: I believe `object` is the parent of all classes (except maybe itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        print('A.__init__ called')
        self.a = a
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print('A.__init__ finished')

class B:
    def __init__(self, b, **kwargs):
        print('B.__init__ called')
        self.b = b
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print('B.__init__ finished')

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, c, **kwargs):
        print('C.__init__ called')
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print('C.__init__ finished')
```

When you create a `C` object, the output is as follows:

```
>>> C(a=1, b=2, c=3)
C.__init__ called
A.__init__ called
B.__init__ called
B.__init__ finished
A.__init__ finished
C.__init__ finished
<__main__.C object at 0x7fd15abcab70>
```

From the order that the `__init__` methods are called, and the fact that they finish in *reverse* order, we can see that `C.__init__` calls `A.__init__`, which calls `B.__init__`. That is, although `A` has no explicit parent class (so its direct parent is `object`), the `super().__init__` call in `A` actually calls `B.__init__`.

This is because `B` is the next class after `A` in `C`'s [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) (MRO). The `A` class needs to call `super()` because although its superclass is `object`, Python allows multiple inheritance, so `A` cannot guarantee that it is the last class before `object` in the MRO.

```py
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

See Raymond Hettinger's article [*Python's super() considered super!*](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for a more detailed explanation about the MRO and "cooperative multiple inheritance techniques".

Comment: I see... This may be a silly question you may have answered and didn't understood, but wouldn't it work the same without the ```super().__init__(**kwargs)``` in class A? The MRO says that since the line is ```class C(A, B)```, C will first "call" A since it's the first class it inherits, followed by B, the second one. As i see it, the MRO wouldn't change if class A didn't had that ```super().__init__(**kwargs)```.

Comment: The MRO says that `C`'s `super()` call will resolve to `A`. The MRO also says that `A`'s `super()` call will resolve to `B`. If you delete the `super()` call from `A` then `B.__init__` will not be called from `C`. If `C`'s `super()` called both `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` then the order would be *"C called, A called, A finished, B called, B finished, C finished"*, but that's not what we see in the output.

Answer (score -1):

> In simple terms...why would i need to use super() in a parent class?

You don't. Unless the parent class is itself a child of another higher class there is no reason to call `super()` in the parent class and it looks like the tutorial you're reading might have accidentally just copy/pasted some additional code.

On another note, you also don't need the () brackets to define a class and furthermore unless you're working in Python2 (which you shouldn't be in 2020 as [Python2.x is no longer supported from 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/)) you don't need to add `(object)` behind a class name, as that was purely a way for classic Python2 classes to take on the new style format, but in Python3 all classes are new style classes.

So, the correct way for your code above to appear would be the following:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__')
        # you don't need a super() here as class A isn't inheriting anything

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B.__init__')
        # you don't need the super() here either as B also isn't inheriting anything

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('C.__init__')
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: For reference, this is the text i was reading, it said it was a "cooperative inheritance": https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127

Comment: And this is a solution a kind person provided in a previous question i had that used super in the parent class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814330/inheritance-and-dunder-methods/59815129

Comment: This is explicitly not the correct way - your `C` class doesn't call `B.__init__`, because `A.__init__` doesn't call `super().__init__`. See my answer.